# Visual Studio 2015 - Azure Notification Hubs - Info Lacking

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-notificationhub

I have VS Enterprise 2015, Update 3.  The Microsoft Azure Cloud Explorer details for Azure Notification Hubs is lacking the good stuff show [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn530751.aspx#Anchor_1), namely the UI shown in the 'todolisthub Notification Hub' Visual Studio display.  Is this something that broke with VS 2015 ... and if so will it be updated?  Have others gotten the information to display in Visual Studio as shown in the article?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the article you linked, you (surprisingly) need to view the Notification Hub in the Server Explorer, not the Cloud Explorer to see that view.

Comment: Yep - the information is in Server Explorer.  I must have assumed that Cloud Explorer, as an Azure-specific-add-in, must have been what the writer meant.